# I will upgrade my laptop's RAM soon - does Ubuntu support this out of the box?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, upgrade, laptop, ram

I want to upgrade the RAM of my laptop. I found the 8 GB RAM stick that is compatible with my laptop. So, if I remove the old RAM stick and place in the new one, will Ubuntu support it out of the box or do I need to install a driver or something similar?

P.S. I can't access the BIOS.

Comment: What CPU do you have? And why can't you access the BIOS? Is this a school or work computer?

Answer (score 1):

When the new 8 GB RAM device is completely compatible with the hardware specifications of the notebook, there is nothing to be done additionally. When you boot the Ubuntu operating system, it will automatically recognize the new device and use the amount of 8 GB memory. You can read some additional information in the answer to this similar question : [Ubuntu settings after adding additional RAM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/733112/ubuntu-settings-after-adding-additional-ram/733116)

Comment: Yep no worries! done that.
But remember to update your swap space, else you risk hypernating and suspend dosnt  work!